# How does Fortran return arrays?

Tags: c, interop, fortran, gnu, fortran90

The subroutine `Rule_Tn` in the Fortran library CUBPACK needs a parameter `Integrand` describing the integrated vector function. It's a

```
INTERFACE 
   FUNCTION Integrand(NF,X) RESULT(Value)
      USE Precision_Model
      INTEGER,                       INTENT(IN)  :: NF
      REAL(KIND=STND), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN)  :: X
      REAL(KIND=STND), DIMENSION(NF)             :: Value
   END FUNCTION Integrand
END INTERFACE
```

Since I want to call `Rule_Tn` from C code I need to define a function type in C exactly matching to this interface above. Thus I tried figure out how a Fortran function returns arrays. At first I supposed the following C signature

```
void Integrand(double* value, const int* nf, const int* x);
```

matches to the interface above. But far wrong! I got a segfault. And I already tested that double is the corresponding type to `REAL(KIND=STND)`, the `STND` comes out of the module `Precision_Model`.

Now can anyone tell me what's the right signature? I'm using the GNU Fortran and C compilers.

Answer (score 1):

See [GNU docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperable-Subroutines-and-Functions.html). It looks like you provided the arguments in a different order between Fortran and C. Try putting `value` last in the C prototype.

Also, you are missing `bind(C)` on the `FUNCTION` line.

Comment: That's not the point, the value of `STND` is defined in the module `Precision_Model` and I already tested that `REAL(KIND=STND)` corresponds to `double`. The question is: What's the corresponding C signature to this interface?

Comment: @phlipsy: you might want to change the "provided that" wording, then. Updating answer.

Comment: Ok I restated that part of my question.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Of course, the source code of CUBPACK is open and I can modify it to match my needs (using the iso_c_binding module as you suggested) but at first I want to get by without any modifications in the Fortran code.

Comment: @philpsy: I highly recommend using the ISO C Binding as a straightforward and portable way of connecting C & Fortran.  If you don't want to modify the original Fortran Source code you could write a small Fortran interface routine that is called by your C-code using the ISO C Binding, and which calls the original Fortran routine with the original interface (not ISO C Binding).

Comment: @MSB: The way how arrays are returned by Fortran isn't standardized? In this case it really would be the best thing to use these ISO C bindings.

Comment: @phipsy: No, the language standard does not specify the calling conventions of Fortran.   That is considered an implementation choice of the compiler vendor.  If you use the ISO C Binding then the language standard requires consistency between the Fortran and C compilers of the same vendor.     (Indeed, Intel ifort and gcc are consistent, even though from different authors.)  And your code will be portable to the pair of compilers of a different vendor.
Also, I'm not sure that the ISO C Binding supports array-valued function returns.  You might need to make your glue-routine a subroutine.

Comment: @MSB: You're right! I tested `BIND(C)` on a array-valued function: gfortran rejected it. Thank you for the informations!